# Make container stop itself

Tags: bash, docker

Is there any native way to make a Docker container stop itself? I can't find anything in the documentation.

I have a container that does some stuff, and I want to hook into the completion of that.

One way I thought of doing this was blocking with `docker wait` until the container stops itself, and then I can restart it with a `docker start` and continue on to the subsequent commands that depend on those jobs being complete.

For instance:

```
docker run -d --name=my-container ...

# Wait for my-container to stop itself
docker wait my-container

# Once it stops itself, start it again.
docker start my-container

# Some other commands here that depend on my-container to finish its jobs...
```

But I can't find any way on the documentation to make a container stop itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `docker stop` to stop a container from outside. To stop a container from inside, you could kill the entrypoint process (the process specified in your `docker run` command, or the `ENTRYPOINT` or last `CMD` specified in the `Dockerfile`, etc.).

Comment: `docker stop` won't be of any help here (though I suppose I could ssh into the host network and run a docker stop, that could probably work as well), but good idea on killing the `ENTRYPOINT` process. Makes perfect sense now that I think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run the container in detached mode (remove the -d)  It'll run in the foreground until the entrypoint/cmd exits.

You may need to use the pseudo-tty (-t) command-line option.

Comment: That works, but can't do that here. The entrypoint should never exit on most runs of the container. It should only exit for this one particular case. I pass it an "on complete" script to run, which will kill the entrypoint process, thus triggering my `docker wait`. Good idea though, thumbs up.